# window confirm print the html tag in ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show the confirmation window for the user who want to delete the data from database.

And I use this confirm() function to achieve this:

```
var str = document.getElementById("myHiddenDiv").innerHTML;

if (confirm(str))
    {
        $.ajax(...

<div id="myHiddenDiv" style="display: none;"><strong>Dont delete this</strong>
<br />
...
</div>
```

However it prints the html attribute in the windows confirmation such as the tag of `<strong>` and `<br/>`. I don't want that. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the text from selected div like

```
var str = document.getElementById("myHiddenDiv").innerText;
```

Or you can also getting text with

```
var str = document.getElementById("myHiddenDiv").textContent;
```

Comment: the window confirmation is blank with the first option. The second one is handling that. Thanks.

Comment: However the second one doesn't make the tag attribute to work properly, it doesn't strong the text. The `</br>` is working.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a modal window to this,  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height:140,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Delete all items": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      //$.ajax(...
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      //$.ajax(...
    }
  }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's good. But how to combine it with ajax post in this line `if (confirm(str))`? Can you please give me an example?